# can we get call a back response from facebook share dialogue box

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sharer

Can we get a callback response from facebook share dialogue box?

I have created a custom share button and trying to get the response from there.
But its giving me a success response on clicking cancel button also  in share dialogue

```
<script>
   window.fbAsyncInit = function(){
   FB.init({
      appId: '782351051797017', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true }); 
   };
   (function(d, debug){var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];if   (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);}(document, /*debug*/ false));

   function postToFeed(title, desc, url, image){
      var obj = {
         method: 'feed',
         link: url, 
         picture: 'http://www.url.com/images/'+image,
         name: title,
         description: desc
      };
      function callback(response){
         console.log('test');
      }
      FB.ui(obj, callback);
   }
</script>

<a href="" data-image="article-1.jpg" data-title="Article Title" data-desc="Some description for this article" id="btnShare">Share</a>

<script>
     $('#btnShare').click(function(){
        elem = $(this);
        postToFeed(elem.data('title'), elem.data('desc'), elem.prop('href'), elem.data('image'));
        return false;
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've used to help us understand your problem..

Comment: Edited,
please guide.

Comment: Where you saw the success message? You've written `console.log("test");`?

Comment: Why do you need to know if the user shared something?

Comment: because i wanted to give the discount,if user shared my page on facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got the solution,i just had to read the response

```
    function callback(response){ 
   if(response==null){
                console.log('test1');
            }
            else{
                console.log('test2');
                 }  
                               }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
```